# Persistent Bitbucket pipeline build artifacts greater than 14 days

Tags: amazon-s3, artifactory, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

I have a pipeline which loses build artifacts after 14 days. I.e, after 14 days, without S3 or Artifactory integration, the pipeline of course loses "Deploy" button functionality - it becomes greyed out since the build artifact is removed. I understand this is by intention by BB/Atlassian to reduce costs etc (detail in below link).

Please check last section of this page "Artifact downloads and Expiry" - https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/

> If you need artifact storage for longer than 14 days (or more than 1
> GB), we recommend using your own storage solution, like Amazon S3 or a
> hosted artifact repository like JFrog Artifactory.

**Question:**
Is anyone able to provide advice or sample code on how to approach BB Pipeline integration with Artifactory (or S3) in order to retain artifacts. Is the Artifactory generic upload/download pipe approach the only way or is the quote above hinting at a more native BB "repository setting" to provide integration with S3 or Artifactory? https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Bitbucket+Pipelines+Artifactory+Pipes

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Bitbucket give an example of linking to an S3 bucket on their site.
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/publish-and-link-your-build-artifacts/

The key is **Step 4** where you link the artefact to the build.

However the example doesn't actually create an artefact that is linked to S3, but rather adds a status code with a description that links to the uploaded item's in S3. To use these in further steps you would then have to download the artefacts.

This can be done using the **aws cli** and an image that has this installed, for example the **amazon/aws-sam-cli-build-image-nodejs14.x** (SAM was required in my case).

The following is an an example that:

1. Creates an artefact ( a txt file ) and uploads to an AWS S3 bucket
2. Creates a "link" as a build status against the commit that triggered the pipeline, as per Amazon's suggestion ( this is just added for reference after the 14 days... meh)
3. Carrys out a "deployment", where by the artefact is downloaded from AWS S3, in this stage I also then set the downloaded S3 artefact as a BitBucket artefact, I mean why not... it may expire after 14 days but at if I've just re-deployed then I may want this available for another 14 days....

```
image: amazon/aws-sam-cli-build-image-nodejs14.x

pipelines:
  branches:
    main:
      - step:
          name: Create artefact
          script:
            - mkdir -p artefacts
            - echo "This is an artefact file..." > artefacts/buildinfo.txt
            - echo "Generating Build Number:\ ${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}" >> artefacts/buildinfo.txt
            - echo "Git Commit Hash:\ ${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}" >> artefacts/buildinfo.txt
            - aws s3api put-object --bucket bitbucket-artefact-test --key ${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}/buildinfo.txt --body artefacts/buildinfo.txt
      - step:
          name: Link artefact to AWS S3
          script:
            - export S3_URL="https://bitbucket-artefact-test.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}/buildinfo.txt"
            - export BUILD_STATUS="{\"key\":\"doc\", \"state\":\"SUCCESSFUL\", \"name\":\"DeployArtefact\", \"url\":\"${S3_URL}\"}"
            - curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --user "${BB_AUTH_STRING}" -d "${BUILD_STATUS}" "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/commit/${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}/statuses/build"
      - step:
          name: Test - Deployment
          deployment: Test
          script:
            - mkdir artifacts
            - aws s3api get-object --bucket bitbucket-artefact-test --key ${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}/buildinfo.txt artifacts/buildinfo.txt
            - cat artifacts/buildinfo.txt
          artifacts:
            - artifacts/**
```

Note:
I've got the following secrets/variables against the repository:

- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
- AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- BB_AUTH_STRING

Answer (score 1):

Bitbucket also has Download section with unlimited (they ask for fair use) storage but an individual file is limited to .5-2 GiB:

- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Downloads-section-storage-limit/qaq-p/617970
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-kind-of-limits-do-you-have-on-repository-file-upload-size-273877699.html

```
curl --verbose --location --request POST -F files=@upload.zip \
   --header 'Authorization: Bearer <token-goes-here>' \
  'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<workspace-name>/<repo-name>/downloads'
```

or see:

- https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-build-artifacts-to-bitbucket-downloads/
- https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file